# Feature Scaling is Linear model

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

How to know that feature scaling is require in Linear Regression, multilinear regression, polynomial regression?  Because some where I am getting a point that feature scaling is not required because coefficient is there and somewhere I am getting that feature scaling is required so what's the actual answer.

Comment: The question is currently a bit vague and open-ended. Try adding a few more specifics, please?

Comment: It is not related to particular problem I am asking it in general mode. Feature scaling is required in linear models or not

Answer (score 2):

Both the statements are correct but incomplete.

If you are using simple linear model such as `y = w1 * x1 + w2 * x2` then feature scaling is not required. As the coefficient `w1` and `w2` will be learned or adapted accordingly.

But if you modify the above expression with the regularization term or defining a constraints over variables, then the coefficient will be biased toward the feature with larger magnitude without feature scaling.

**In conclusion**: `Feature scaling is important when we modify the expression for simple linear model`. Also it is a good practice to normalize the features before applying any algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have two features of weight and price, as in the below table. The “Weight” cannot have a meaningful comparison with the “Price.” So the assumption algorithm makes that since “Weight” > “Price,” thus “Weight,” is more important than “Price.” [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-feature-scaling-bcc0ad75cb35)

Feature scaling is required when the data columns have large variation in their ranges. Getting the `min`, `max` and `mean` of the data in each column is great way

Plotting the data is a next. This identifies the range of the different dimensions of the data easily.